# AMRestoreErrorDomain error 14 when "restoring" iPad with Apple Configurator 2.

Tags: ipad, apple-configurator

I've run into an issue provisioning an iPad with Apple Configurator 2. I was in the process of redeploying an iPad from a former employee to a new employee, and noticed that I couldn't find Safari on the iPad, so I decided to just reimage it with Apple Configurator 2 (and our MDM platform).  I figured I'd just restore it to factory default, provision it with our blueprint, get it on our MDM and be done with it, however, at some point in the restore process, Apple Configurator throws this unuseful error, and the device is stuck with a tiny bit of progress on the iOS installation screen.

[image]

I was able to find a second device that (presumably) ran into the same problem, and when unplugged from the Apple Configurator, I get the iTunes connect a cable a screen.  Even the power button seems to no longer work, and attempts to reimage these devices don't get any further than where they're currently stuck.

[image]

Anyone run into this before, or have any suggestions on what to do, now that we seem to be creating iBricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out [in nitronblue's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254197/167551), the iPad can be "unbricked" by doing a firmware restore through iTunes.  The devices seem to have gotten stuck in [DFU mode](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/DFU_Mode), and iTunes was the easiest way (by far) to get them bootable again.

As far as fixing the issue, the Mac Mini I was running Configurator from had a [macOS Server update (v5.2)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207027) available that was released on September 20th.  Applying the update and rebooting has allowed me to successfully provision iPads again.

Answer (score 3):

I came here looking for a solution to this very problem. Fwiw, I find that I can un-brick the iPad by closing AC2 and restoring it in iTunes. Unfortunately, that does not supervise the device.

Comment: Doing what you describe did, indeed, allow me to restore the firmware and get the iPad into a functional state again, so thank you.

Comment: You can install the firmware via iTunes, then add provisioning profiles through AC2.